# Strange Cudamemcpy execution time

Tags: cuda

I'm currently working on a Cuda code which computes a simple difference pixel by pixel of two images (size: 2560x1706 px) in order to compare execution time of CPU and GPU.

I realize a "for" loop of 1000 iterations of my kernel to have a more significant execution time, and I perform the cudaMemcpy (from device to host) straight after the loop to retrieve the data computed.

Nevertheless, the execution time of this cudaMemcpy took 2800 ms which is higher than expected. I just was asking myself why I obtain such a result.

Here is my Kernel Code :

```
__global__ void diff (unsigned char *data1 ,unsigned char *data2, int  *data_res)
{
  int v = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

  if (v < N)
  {
    data_res[v] = (int) data2[v] - (int) data1[v];
  }
}
```

Here is the kernel calls :

```
    cudaProfilerStart();

    // Cuda allocation
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_data1, N*sizeof(unsigned char));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_data2, N*sizeof(unsigned char));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_data_res, N*sizeof(int));

    // Cuda memory copy
    cudaMemcpy(dev_data1, img1->data, N*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaMemcpy(dev_data2, img2->data, N*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_data_res, imgresult->data, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Simulate nb_loops images
    for(int m = 0; m < nb_loops ; m++)
    {
        diff<<<blck_nb, thrd_nb>>>(dev_data1, dev_data2, dev_data_res);
        //printf("%4d", m);
    }


    printf("WAITING FOR MEMCPY...\n");

    clock_t begin = clock(), diff;

    cudaMemcpy(imgresult_data, dev_data_res, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    diff = clock() - begin;
    float msec = diff*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\t \nTime of the MEMCPY : %2.3f ms\n", msec);

    printf("MEMCPY DEVICE TO HOST OK!\n");

    cudaProfilerStop();
```

And here is the screenshot of the execution time results :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Kernel launches are asynchronous, so your timing is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA kernel launches are asynchronous, and `cudaMemcpy` is a blocking call. So what you are calling memcpy time is really kernel execution + memcpy tiime. Change your code like this:

```
...
for(int m = 0; m < nb_loops ; m++)
{
    diff<<<blck_nb, thrd_nb>>>(dev_data1, dev_data2, dev_data_res);
    //printf("%4d", m);
}

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
printf("WAITING FOR MEMCPY...\n");
....
```

and this timing should be correct.

Comment: This effectively gave me the right cudaMemcpy execution time after the assertion of cudaDeviceSynchronize().
However, I use a NVIDIA GT720 and the GPU execution time is just 6 times faster than the CPU execution time. What do you think about that ? Shouldn't be something like 100 times faster ? Does it seem consistent ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Flow: You are running your code on the slowest near current GPU model that NVIDIA produce. Six times speed up seems entirely reasonable. Hundreds of times does not.